# Why do I need aliases in self join?

Tags: sql, join

I'm learning SQL and happen to hang on a point that confuses me:

I got 1 table with 1 column (boys.boy) while boy is a varchar.

```
SELECT boys.boy, boys.boy 
FROM boys 
LEFT JOIN boys 
  ON length(boy) > length(boy)
```

Why am I unable to do this? Would this break some invariant, or why did the inventors explicitly bring in "self-joins"?

In other words, this works ("self join"):

```
SELECT b1.boy, b2.boy 
FROM boys AS b1 
INNER JOIN boys AS b2 
  ON length(b1.boy) > length(b2.boy)
```

The magic lies in the aliases (AS ...).

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve?

Comment: @musefan: I try to understand why they built the language like that. I'm sure this has some purpose, but I don't get it. :)

Answer (score 8):

You **have** to use aliases in this case.

Otherwise server can't distinguish one `boys.boy` from another, and this construction

```
length(boy) > length(boy)
```

is pretty ambiguous - since it can be interpreted as

```
length(b1.boy) > length(b2.boy)
```

or

```
length(b2.boy) > length(b1.boy)
```

or even

```
length(b1.boy) > length(b1.boy)
```

**Update**

Consider this simple snippet (t-sql used here):

```
declare @boys table (boy nvarchar(128))

insert into @boys
select 'Ed'
union
select 'Tom'
union
select 'Nick'

select b1.boy, b2.boy
from @boys as b1
    left outer join @boys as b2 on len(b1.boy) > len(b2.boy)

select b1.boy, b2.boy
from @boys as b1
    left outer join @boys as b2 on len(b2.boy) > len(b1.boy)
```

Output from first query will be

```
Ed      NULL
Nick    Ed
Nick    Tom
Tom     Ed
```

And from the second one:

```
Ed      Nick
Ed      Tom
Nick    NULL
Tom     Nick
```

Explanation:

Let's have a look at first query. It is basically: "take all records from table and combine each record with all other records having length of boy's name less than that record has". That's why whe getting `Ed, Null` pair - there are no records having length of name **less** than `Ed` has.

But in the second query condition is "take all records from table and combine each record with all other records having length of boy's name **greater** than that record has". That's why we're getting pairs `Ed, Nick` and `Ed, Tom` in this case.

Comment: I think I didn't express myself clear, sorry for that. I wanted to ask WHY they made it like that. Why does the server need to distinguish `boys.boy` from another? If it works with aliases it should somehow also work without, I don't understand why it needs to be distinguished?

Comment: @TrudleR well, when joining a tables - you have two sets of data and some joining condition. If this condition is ambiguous - you can't determine, how you should join data sets, don't you? How show data from "right" table be linked - having length of boy column greater or smaller than in "left" table?

Comment: I doesn't matter how it is interpreted, because b1 and b2 are the same table. That's why I'm asking. It doesn't matter how it's being interpreted, because all of your examples lead to the same result.

Comment: @TrudleR - no, each example leads to different result. For example `length(b1.boy) > length(b1.boy)` satisfies no records, other examples give different results too.

Comment: I just tried it and you're right. I don't get why there is this difference. I need a coffee break. Maybe I can think better afterwards. Thank you anyways for your help, I will answer back later. :)

Comment: @TrudleR: It's the same *table*, but not the same *record*. So one match would be b1.boy = 'Johnny' and b2.boy = 'John' for instance. So you must say the boy of which record you are taking about. For example let's add `AND boy LIKE '%`'`. This is true for the b1.boy and false for the b2.boy. So which of the boys do you want this restriction for?

Comment: @TrudleR: This has nothing to do with self-joins only, btw. If you have products with a price and these consist of parts having a price each and you join the tables to get a product with its parts and you say `WHERE price < 10`, it's again: which price? Do you only want products costing less than 10? Or are you only interested in parts costing less than 10? You need a qualifyer, i.e. the table name or its alias. With self joins at least one of the two tables needs an alias in order to be able  to qualify which of the two you are referring to.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I think I get the picture. The "alias" thing isn't just a shortcut, it's also like declaring a "variable" if you put it in the context of a programming language. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`ON` clauses can contain arbitrary predicates. Although it's *common* to see a join like this:

```
FROM Table1
         INNER JOIN
     Table2
         ON
            Table1ColumnA = Table2ColumnC and
            Table1ColumnB = Table2ColumnD
```

it is by no means *required* that the columns on the left are references from the first table and columns on the right are references to the second table.

For instance, when trying to find intervals that overlap, I would commonly construct a join as:

```
FROM
    Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    Table1 t2
        ON
             t1.Start < t2.End AND
             t2.Start < t1.End AND
             t1.ID != t2.ID
```

Note that the tables being used in each comparison are the opposite way around.

This also means that you can do more complex joins:

```
FROM
    Table1 t1
         LEFT JOIN
    Table2 t2
         ON
            t2.ID = t1.ID
         LEFT JOIN
    Table3 t3
         ON
             t1.ColB = t3.ColF
         INNER JOIN
    Table4 t4
         ON
               t4.ColA = t2.ColC OR
               t3.ColZ = t4.ColY
```

Which is effectively performing an `INNER JOIN` between tables 1 and 4 using *either* Table 2 *or* Table 3 (or both).

As I said at the top - the `ON` clauses can contain arbitrary predicates.